# Java Spring внедрение java.sql.Connection в объект

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

У меня есть такой DAO-класс, который я хочу отрефакторить и переписать на спринге:

```
package data;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BlockchainIndexDAO {

    private Connection connection;
    private static final String SELECT_DISTINCT_TX_ID = "select distinct transaction_id from car_blockchain_index";

    public BlockchainIndexDAO(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public List<String> getTransactionList() {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Statement st = connection.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SELECT_DISTINCT_TX_ID);
            while (rs.next()) {
                result.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Спринг мне нужен для внедрения зависимостей, чтобы создавать объекты со всеми зависимостями. DAO работает с постгресом. Как при помощи DI спринга внедрить в это DAO объект Connection?

Comment: Spring сам умеет контролировать подключение к бд. Вам нужно создать конфиг для `dataSource`. И в `DAO` класс подсунуть `entityManager` или `sessionFactory`

Comment: Написать конфигурацию для создания Connection, и использовать инекцию в конструктор

Answer (score 0):

Начну с того что инжектить `Connection` в `DAO`, это неправильно, в таком случае за все время работы приложения у вас будет один конекшн который постоянно открыт. Если вы в приложении не используете никаких ORM фреймворков вам стоит инжектить в DAO или же `DataSource` обьект с которого вы сможете получить конекшн или же использовать спринговый `JdbcTemplate` который немного упрощает процес разработки. Я бы рекомендовал использовать `JdbcTemplate`, пример использования можно найти здесь:

https://www.journaldev.com/17053/spring-jdbctemplate-example